# Can't obtain reference to EKReminder array retrieved from fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, ekeventstore

When I create an NSPredicate via EKEventStore predicateForRemindersInCalendars; and pass it to EKEventStore fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:completion:^ I can loop through the reminders array provided by the completion code block, but when I try to store a reference to the reminders array, or create a copy of the array into a local variable or instance variable, both array's remain empty. The reminders array is never copied to them.

This is the method I am using, in the method, I create a predicate, pass it to the event store and then loop through all of the reminders logging their title via NSLog. I can see the reminder titles during runtime thanks to NSLog, but the local arrayOfReminders object is empty. I also try to add each reminder into an instance variable of NSMutableArray, but once I leave the completion code block, the instance variable remains empty.

Am I missing something here? Can someone please tell me why I can't grab a reference to all of the reminders for use through-out the app? I am not having any issues at all accessing and storing EKEvents, but for some reason I can't do it with EKReminders.

```
- (void)findAllReminders {

    NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForRemindersInCalendars:nil];

    __block NSArray *arrayOfReminders = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    [self.eventStore fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:predicate completion:^(NSArray *reminders) {

        arrayOfReminders = [reminders copy]; //Does not work.

        for (EKReminder *reminder in reminders) {

            [self.remindersForTheDay addObject:reminder];

            NSLog(@"%@", reminder.title);
       }
   }];

   //Always = 0;
   if ([self.remindersForTheDay count]) {
       NSLog(@"Instance Variable has reminders!");
   }

    //Always = 0;
   if ([arrayOfReminders count]) {
       NSLog(@"Local Variable has reminders!");
   }
}
```

The eventStore getter is where I perform my instantiation and get access to the event store.

```
- (EKEventStore *)eventStore {
   if (!_eventStore) {
       _eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

        //respondsToSelector indicates iOS 6 support.
       if ([_eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {
           //Request access to user calendar
           [_eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
               if (granted) {
                   NSLog(@"iOS 6+ Access to EventStore calendar granted.");
               } else {
                   NSLog(@"Access to EventStore calendar denied.");
               }
           }];

            //Request access to user Reminders
           [_eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
               if (granted) {
                   NSLog(@"iOS 6+ Access to EventStore Reminders granted.");
               } else {
                   NSLog(@"Access to EventStore Reminders denied.");
               }
           }];
       } else { //iOS 5.x and lower support if Selector is not supported
           NSLog(@"iOS 5.x < Access to EventStore calendar granted.");
       }

        for (EKCalendar *cal in self.calendars) {
           NSLog(@"Calendar found: %@", cal.title);
       }

       [_eventStore reset];
   }

    return _eventStore;
}
```

Lastly, just to show that I am initializing my remindersForTheDay instance variable using lazy instantiation.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)remindersForTheDay {
   if (!_remindersForTheDay) _remindersForTheDay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    return _remindersForTheDay;
}
```

I've read through the Apple documentation and it doesn't provide any explanation that I can find to answer this. I read through the [Blocks Programming docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW3) and it states that you can access local and instance variables without issues from within a block, but for some reason, the above code does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've scoured Google for answers but have yet to get this figured out.

Thanks everyone!

Johnathon.

**UPDATE**:

I have since created a new app that does nothing but instance an event store, setup a table view, setup a KVO and updates the UI as per the recommendations provided. The code below is the app in its entirety. The UITableView is never updated with the reminders content. The app launches, and stares at me. The reloadData method invocation should eventually have the UI updated with the reminder data.

The reminder data exists in self.reminders, because my NSLog outputs that I have 372 objects in the array.

Lastly, if I touch the UITableView on the device, the app crashes with "'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'".

```
@import EventKit;
#import "RTViewController.h"

@interface RTViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) EKEventStore *eventStore;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *reminders;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL accessGranted;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *date;
@end

@implementation RTViewController

- (EKEventStore *)eventStore {
    if (!_eventStore) {
        _eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

        if ([_eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {
            [_eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                if (granted) self.accessGranted = YES;
                else self.accessGranted = NO;
            }];
        }

        [_eventStore reset];
    }

    return _eventStore;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.reminders = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    self.date = [NSDate date]; //Returns NSDate allocated/init to NOW

    NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForRemindersInCalendars:nil]; //nil will cause all calendars to be used.

    //Ran on different thread.
    [self.eventStore fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:predicate completion:^(NSArray *reminders) {
        _reminders = [reminders copy]; //NEVER happens.
        [self updateReminders];
    }];

    //Setup the "radio" and watch ourself for when self.reminders is changed from the other thread
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"reminders" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:NULL];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //If no data exists, then this will return 0 so no rows created.
    return [self.reminders count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (self.reminders) {
        EKReminder *reminder = self.reminders[indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = reminder.title;
    }

    return cell;
}

//Called by self when self.remidners is changed. - NEVER gets called.
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)updateReminders {
    NSLog(@"%d objects found in array", [self.reminders count]);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
@end
```

Comment: The first problem with the update is that you are accessing `_reminders` directly, instead of using `self.reminders`. The former will never fire up any KVO. The second problem might be that you might be updating the UI (calling `reloadData`) outside the main thread. I will recommend using something like `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self.tableView reloadData]; }`. Third, I don’t see that you’re registering cells, so you need to check for `cell` being `nil`, and create one from scratch. Any basic `UITableView` tutorial should show you how.

Comment: I had actually done just that Sunday night,  the update UI call going to the main thread fixed it. As of iOS 6, you don't have to register the cells, the table view will instance a new one for you of one does not exist, provided that the cell was created in interface builder (mine was). Putting the update UI call on the main thread and setting up KVO fixed the issue for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also, Apples documentation said that you can only access instance variables directly and not their properties from within a code block, thus the reason I accessed using _reminders. I ended up just setting self.reminders = reminders; in a different method and called it from within the code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is that the “completion block” executes “a lot later” (in computer time) than the code you mark as “Always = 0”.

Generally speaking, if a block is called “completion” in Apple APIs, it will run asynchronously: Apple will save your block, run the fetch you asked for, and then invoke your block with the results. The results will not be ready when the method `fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:completion:` returns, only when your completion block is invoked. This is confirmed by the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009567-CH1-SW13) where they say: “This method fetches reminders asynchronously.”.

So, you need to move your logic into the callbacks…

```
- (void)findAllReminders {
  NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForRemindersInCalendars:nil];

  // I removed the arrayOfReminders, I think it wasn’t necessary, and was just to show
  // your problem.

  [self.eventStore fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:predicate completion:^(NSArray *reminders) {
    for (EKReminder *reminder in reminders) {
        [self.remindersForTheDay addObject:reminder];
        // You probably were seing this logging, right?
        NSLog(@"%@", reminder.title);
    }
    [self refreshUI];
  }];
}

- (void)refreshUI {
  // Do whatever you need to do with the UI in refreshUI, inside it, the
  // self.remindersForTheDay will be already filled.
}
```

The problem know is your eventStore method, since you can see that it also have a “completion” callback, it will not always be able to return a value immediately, so you need to change your logic a little bit.

```
// Instead of returning the value directly, we will return the value in our own
// completion callback.
// The first argument will be a block that accepts an EKEventStore as parameter.
- (void)performWithEventStore:(void (^)(EKEventStore *eventStore))completion {
  if (!completion) return; // if no completion callback is provided, just return.

  if (!_eventStore) {
    _eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    if ([_eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {
      // Request access to user calendar
      [_eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted) {
          // We have been granted access, invoke our completion, and let them do the
          // work
          // Be careful, because here, we are in an arbitrary queue, you might want to
          // switch to the main queue here or later.
          completion(_eventStore);
        } else {
          // you haven’t been given access, you should probably show an error
          NSLog(@"Access to EventStore calendar denied.");
          // you might want to nilify _eventStore here.
        }
      }];

      // I think you cannot use the same store to access reminders and event, but I’m
      // not sure. You might need to different instances of EKEventStore (following
      // this example, two methods: performWithEventsStore and
      // performWithRemindersStore)
    } else { //iOS 5.x and lower support if Selector is not supported
      // Because 5.x gives access immediately, just call our completion block
      completion(_eventStore);
    }
  } else {
    // A previous call to this method created the event store, just invoke the
    // callback with the saved event store.
    completion(_eventStore);
  }
}
```

Then, the `findAllReminders` method have to be changed as follows:

```
- (void)findAllReminders {
  NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForRemindersInCalendars:nil];

  [self performWithEventStore:^(EKEventStore *eventStore) {
    // We are using the eventStore parameter of the block
    [eventStore fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:predicate completion:^(NSArray *reminders) {
      for (EKReminder *reminder in reminders) {
          [self.remindersForTheDay addObject:reminder];
          // You probably were seing this logging, right?
          NSLog(@"%@", reminder.title);
      }
      [self refreshUI];
    }];
  }];
}
```

Yes, that’s a completion block inside a completion block. This is because you are dealing with two asynchronous processes here: asking authorization to the user, and fetching the events from event store.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I wish I could buy you a beer! So, is there a reason why you call performWithEventStore:^ to check authorization instead of just doing it on the first time the instance is instantiated? Also, since this code is in my model, and my model does not have access to my UI (where I would need to put a refreshUI method), should I add a delegate to the ViewController to my model? So I can invoke [self.delegate refreshUI]; ? This data is stored in a model that a UITableViewCell uses to present the data to the end user.

Comment: Ah, I think I've got a solution. I'll setup something using the [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html). I'll mess with this tonight and see if I can get this linked up with my View Controller.

Comment: I have updated my original post to show a new example. The issue is still unresolved unfortunately. I can not get the EKReminders stored in the code block, onto the UI. Do you have any further suggestions?